# A question about Inverted Pendulum on a wheeler, its governing equations of motion and Lagrangian analysis

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism

I was inspecting some papers about inverted pendulum TMD type stabilizers unfortunately I'm not into structural things and couldn't understand some part of governing equations of motion especially the one about the pendulum's bar. I derived the kinetic energy equations for the pendulum's mass ($T_m$) and the wheeler ($T_c$) but how could the author derived that kind of equation for the pendulum's bar($T_{\rm bar}$), I just couldn't get it. I need enlightenment.

[image: iptmd]

Comment: It's done by dividing the rod into infinitesimal mass elements $dl$, each infintesimal element has the same form as the block $m$ at the end. What's left for you is to just do the integration over the whole rod of the K.E of each elementnt.

Comment: @aitfel can you suggest a source for better understanding and further reading, thanks.

Comment: try ch-$2$ of https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/analytical-mechanics/7145C0BF476388E6841B44064515909E

Comment: thanks so much!